# Customize AppbarLayout with customview

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using the CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout. Below AppBarLayout, I have a RecyclerView with a list of content. In AppbarLayout I have custom View as Toolbar. And below that view, I have another custom View. I have set the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to toolbar and `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` to the custom view.

It's working correctly except for one issue. When there is a fling in recycleview, the last part of custom view gets visible. But I want to the toolbar to get visible on fling in recycleview(on upward scroll). I have tried to draw my view as much clear as I can. 
My main view.

[image: my main view]

It's behaving like this right now.

[image]

What I want to achieve.
[image]

My MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/navbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/weather"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/weather"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Dhaka"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#FF4A4A4A"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/weather"
                android:gravity="right" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/temperature"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#FF4A4A4A"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/weather"
                android:layout_below="@id/location"
                android:gravity="right"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/brand_logo"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rn_logo" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/brand_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="RIDMIK NEWS"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#212933"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/brand_logo"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#FF9B9B9B"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/brand_logo"
                android:layout_below="@id/brand_title"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/spprts_score_segment_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.UI.FontNavigationButton
        android:id="@+id/feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:iconSize="7sp"
        app:iconUnicode="@string/bottom_icon_now"
        app:middleSpace="5dp"
        app:topPadding="10dp"
        app:usageText="now"
        app:usageTextSize="3sp" />

    <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.UI.FontNavigationButton
        android:id="@+id/briefing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:iconSize="7sp"
        app:iconUnicode="\ue802"
        app:middleSpace="5dp"
        app:topPadding="10dp"
        app:usageText="briefing"
        app:usageTextSize="3sp" />

    <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.UI.FontNavigationButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:iconSize="7sp"
        app:iconUnicode="\ue803"
        app:middleSpace="5dp"
        app:topPadding="10dp"
        app:usageText="add story"
        app:usageTextSize="3sp" />

    <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.UI.FontNavigationButton
        android:id="@+id/topics"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:iconSize="7sp"
        app:iconUnicode="\ue805"
        app:middleSpace="5dp"
        app:topPadding="10dp"
        app:usageText="@string/menu_bottom_topics_en"
        app:usageTextSize="3sp" />

    <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.UI.FontNavigationButton
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:iconSize="7sp"
        app:iconUnicode="\ue806"
        app:middleSpace="10dp"
        app:topPadding="10dp"
        app:usageText="@string/menu_bottom_profile_en"
        app:usageTextSize="3sp" />

</LinearLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

spprts_score_segment_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/live_score_view"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cricket_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/upper"
        android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/segment_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sports_live"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#15DEA8"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_update_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.customClass.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_view"
            app:fontName="ridmik.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="\ue81d"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/score_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.customClass.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/first_team_flag"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/flag_australia"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_team_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@id/first_team_flag"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="vs"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white_with_alpha"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/second_team_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@id/first_team_flag"/>

            <com.ridmic.rc.newsic.customClass.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/second_team_flag"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/flag_australia"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_name_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/score_layer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_team_run"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#353B50"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first_team_over"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_team_flag"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#353B50"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/second_team_run"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#353B50"
                android:gravity="right"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/second_team_over"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_team_flag"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#353B50"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollIndicators="none"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latest_score_layer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/team_name_layer"
            android:scrollbars = "horizontal"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textScaleX ="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/icomoon"
            android:textColor="@null"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:scrollIndicators="none"
            android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
            android:text=""/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/player_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/latest_score_layer">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/batsman_layer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/batsman_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/batsman"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#353B50"
                android:textSize="9sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/batsman_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/first_batsman_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/second_batsman_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bowler_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bowler"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#353B50"
                android:textSize="9sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/bowler_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bowler_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bowler_over"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="10sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/match_status"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/player_layer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope I have explained my question clearly.

Comment: please share your main activity xml layout, that's all we need to see :)

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you use the CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: You wrote you have a RecyclerView, but I can't see any in xml ... instead, I see a lots of LinearLayout(s), which is clearly wrong ... get rid of them, and use a RecyclerView class following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with this flag `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed` as `AppBarLayout` child:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        ...
        ..
```

And add `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to your `Toolbar` in order to when `CollapsingToolbarLayout` collapsed, `Toolbar` should stay at the place.

**Output:**

[image]

**Check the sample:** https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

As a note, using too many `LinearLayout`s or `RelativeLayout` ***is not recommended***.

Answer (score 0):

This is the hierarchy you want to have [collapsing-toolbar-layout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Scrollable view here -->
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_activity_main_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tall_toolbar_height">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

      <!-- your custom view goes here-->

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

whereas as you can see the RecyclerView is draw before the AppBarLayout, which wraps around the CollapsingToolbarLayout, which (note) contains the Toolbar as your last view, and your custom view on top of it.
Then you can set the behavioral part properly via Toolbar's *app:layout_collapseMode* and CollapsingToolbarLayout's *app:layout_scrollFlags*.